# cannot run C compiled programs while installing GCC4.7

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gcc4.7

> there is some problem while installing GCC4.7 . Please help me fix this error.
>   http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/04/13/building-gcc-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/
>   I was trying to install GCC4.7 by following those commands in the above site. 
>   prerequistes for gcc are installed properly, When i was trying to call "make" during the installation of Gcc I'm getting the following errors.
>
> ```
> checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
> checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: in `/home/priya/OS_HW1/gcc-4.7/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp':
> configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
> If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
> See `config.log' for more details.
> make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgomp] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/priya/OS_HW1/gcc-4.7/build'
> make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/priya/OS_HW1/gcc-4.7/build'
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Installation seems broken. Try

```
 sudo apt-get install libgomp1 
 sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7-base
```